# Jim and the Skyscrapers - data structures Questn - solved using stack - but not efficient

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

**Problem link :**https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jim-and-the-skyscrapers

**Problem Statement** 
  Let us describe the problem in one dimensional space. We have in total N skyscrapers aligned from left to right. The ith skyscraper has a height of hi. A flying route can be described as (i,j) with i≠j, which means, Jim starts his HZ42 at the top of the skyscraper i and lands on the skyscraper j. Since HZ42 can only fly horizontally, Jim will remain at the height hi only. Thus the path (i,j) can be valid, only if each of the skyscrapers i,i+1,...,j−1,j is not strictly greater than hi and if the height of the skyscraper he starts from and arrives on have the same height. Formally, (i,j) is valid iff ∄k∈[i,j]:hk>hi and hi=hj.

**My Approach :**

I have used stack. If next integer is lesser than top of stack, it is pushed into the stack. If it is greater, **top of stack (first top)** is popped and compared with the top of stack. If they are equal counter is increased and again top is popped and new top is compared with previous **top of stack (first top)**. Process is repeated till **top of stack (first top)** is not equal to the top of stack.

Finally If stack is not empty, I am again counting  duplicate element.
This counters of a specific element are stored in an array list on the fly.

***Is this a good approach? Is stack the right choice? Can my code be improvised to speed up?***

My code is correct but few test cases are terminated due to timeout.

**Input Format**

The first line contains N, the number of skyscrapers. The next line contains N space separated integers representing the heights of the skyscrapers.

**Output Format**

Print an integer that denotes the number of valid routes.

**My Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    // method to calculate nCr
    public static long choose(long total, long choose){ 
        if(total < choose)
            return 0;
        if(choose == 0 || choose == total)
            return 1;
        return choose(total-1,choose-1)+choose(total-1,choose);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 1;
        long x = 0;
        Stack s = new Stack();
        ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0 ; i<t ; i++){
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            if(s.isEmpty() || ((int)s.peek()>= a) ){
                s.push(a);
            } else {
                    while(!(s.isEmpty()) && a > (int)s.peek() ){
                    int top = (int)s.pop();
                        while(!(s.isEmpty()) && top == (int)s.peek()){
                        count++;
                        s.pop();
                    }
                    if(count>1){
                        alist.add(count);
                        count=1;
                    }
             }
                s.push(a);
             }
        }

         while(!(s.isEmpty()) ){
                 int tp = (int)s.pop();
                    while(!(s.isEmpty()) && tp == (int)s.peek()){
                        count++;
                        s.pop();
                    }
                    if(count>1){
                          alist.add(count);
                          count=1;
                    }
               }

       for(Integer n : alist){
           x += choose(n,2);
       }

       System.out.println(2*x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your idea handle the input `3,2,1,3,2,1,3` and return that there are three valid routes?

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov Yes. It handles and returns 6 i.e, 3* 2 ; [Check](http://pastie.org/10302606)

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov  [Run this detailed code](http://pastie.org/10302606) in the problem link with custom input of yours. **input:** 1 3  2 1 3 2 1 3

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov because the route is two way. If i = j ,Jim can start at i and travel to j or he can start at j and travel to i.

Answer (score 0):

your approach seems to me somewhat complicated and (consequently) time-consuming.

Here's an alternative which I doubt will ever use any relevant amount of time - in VB; I'm sure you can translate it in whatever language you'd like.
I present only the "heart" of the method (without handling of input and output)

```
Dim result As New SortedDictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Flight)) 'key: index of skyscraper where the flight starts.
Dim flightsWithSameStart As List(Of Flight) = Nothing 'placeholder
Dim hValue As Integer

Dim openFlights As New List(Of Flight)(hValues.Count) 'hValues is a list of (integer) skyscraper heights, provided by the user.

For indx As Integer = 0 To hValues.Count - 1

  hValue = hValues(indx)

  Dim n As Integer = openFlights.Count
  For k As Integer = n - 1 To 0 Step -1

    Dim fl As Flight = openFlights(k)

    If hValue > fl.height Then

      ' Remove the Flight: it cannot continue and (apparently) it hasn't landed.
      openFlights.RemoveAt(k)

    ElseIf hValue = fl.height Then
      ' This flight will branch:
      ' a) it can stop here, landing at this height.
      ' b) it can also continue.
      ' We achieve this by storing a CLONE of the current flight and NOT removing this current flight from the open flights.

      Dim flCopy As Flight = fl.Clone
      flCopy.last = indx
      If Not result.TryGetValue(flCopy.first, flightsWithSameStart) Then
        flightsWithSameStart = New List(Of Flight)
        result.Add(flCopy.first, flightsWithSameStart)
      End If
      flightsWithSameStart.Add(flCopy)

    Else
      Exit For
    End If

  Next

  ' At each skyscraper we hopefully launch another flight.
  Dim flNew As New Flight
  flNew.first = indx
  flNew.height = hValue
  openFlights.Add(flNew)

Next

' Discard any remaining open flights: they cannot land.
' (just ignore whatever is left in 'openFlights')
```

A simple helper class Flight is used:

Private Class Flight

```
Public first As Integer
Public last As Integer
Public height As Integer

Public Function Clone() As Flight
  Dim copy As Flight = CType(Me.MemberwiseClone, Flight)
  Return copy
End Function
```

End Class

Apologize if I made errors (or maybe misunderstood the problem) - just ran a few testcases and they seemed ok to me.

Regards

(forgot to mention that whenever i=>j is a valid path/flight, then so is j=>i, so it suffices to compute the cases with j>i, as in my code (and then reversing them, if you like, to add their mirrors).